# Get a list of failed Jasmine unit tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, gulp

How can I tell Jasmine to write to a file (or object) the failures after a given test run?  For instance, I'm using phantomJs and I would like to run my unit tests, and then somehow use the jasmine API to write to a file the failed tests.  I'm using gulp to bundle/watch/browserify/reactify, etc.  Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Jasmine console reporter, then logging the messages in PhantomJS's onConsoleMessage event handler.

Comment: I didn't know Phantom had this, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: ever had any problems with behavior you see in phantom you don't see in a major vendor browser?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Yes, depending on the version of PhantomJS you are using.  1.9.8 does not support a multitude of things (in my case it was Node.contains), and this is the version that gets pulled down for most test runners that use PhantomJS (karma-phantomjs-launcher in particular). If you install 2.0.0 manually, however, most of these issues go away.